# My .addCard() can't be applied to the given type, what does this mean?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
public FiveCardStud (int numberOfPlayers)
{
    if(numberOfPlayers < 2) 
    { 
        numberOfPlayers = 2; 
        System.out.println("The number of players must be 2 or more. The number of players has been set to 2."); 
    } 
    if(numberOfPlayers > 6) 
    { 

        numberOfPlayers = 6; 
        System.out.println("The number of players must be 6 or more. The number of players has been set to 6."); 
    }
    players = new ArrayList<Hand>();
    myDeck = new Deck();
    for(int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        players.add(new Hand());
    }
}
```

This top half is just here for context more than anything else.

```
/**
 * Deal the cards.
 */
/*
Write a method called "deal".
The method should print out a message to let the user know
that the cards have been dealt.
It should remove any old cards from all players hands
from previous games (Hint: there is a fold method in the Hand class.)
It should then shuffle the deck and add 5 cards to each player's hand.
 */

public void deal()
{
    for(int index = 0; index <= 5; index++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= players.size(); j ++)
        {
            players.get(index).addCard();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the first half of my code, however I can't make my addCard() work. This is a method found within a class.hand

Answer (score 0):

You need to recast it to Hand:

`((Hand)player.get(index)).addCard();`

Comment: It can't find the symbol - class hand with that. Is there a syntax error I'm not seeing?

Comment: sorry `players` not `player`